# How to get all transactions of an address in multi blockchain using TokenView api?

Tags: rest, blockchain, cryptocurrency

I want to analyze incoming and outcoming transactions of multiple addresses across different blockchains using Python, now I am researching available APIs. I have tried blockchair.com, blockchain.com, but they don't have info about some addresses. The best I have found is tokenview.io.

The **TokenViewAPI** is working fine, but the problem is that I need to get info about addresses from different blockchain (btc, bsc, eth, trx, etc.). It is inconvenient because I have to send different requests for each blockchain.

For example:

[https://services.tokenview.io/vipapi/address/btc/{btc_address}/1/50?apikey={}](https://services.tokenview.io/vipapi/address/btc/%7Bbtc_address%7D/1/50?apikey=%7B%7D)

and

[https://services.tokenview.io/vipapi/address/trx/{trx_address}/1/50?apikey={}](https://services.tokenview.io/vipapi/address/trx/%7Btrx_address%7D/1/50?apikey=%7B%7D)

I can't know for sure which blockchain the address belongs to and it seems that there is no universal request for every supported blockchain. How can I get a list of transactions without specifying the blockchain?